# I want cache images without show them in any imageView how do this i want do progress while I´m change to use the by url later

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

```
SDWebImageDownloader *downloader = [SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader];
                [downloader downloadImageWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:url]
                                         options:0
                                        progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
                                            // progression tracking code
                                        }
                                       completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {
                                           if (image && finished) {
}});
```

Comment: please explain in more detial, the title should be used to give a quick summary. then describe your issue, what you've tried and what your trying to acheive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
-(UIImage *)downloadImageAsync:(NSString *)imageKey
{
     NSLog(@"image key : %@",imageKey);
      __block UIImage *returnedImage;
      SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
      [manager downloadWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageKey] options:0 progress:^(NSUInteger receivedSize, long long expectedSize){
       NSLog(@"received size %d expected size %lld", receivedSize, expectedSize);

     }completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType,BOOL finished){
       if(image && finished) {
           returnedImage = image;
       }
  }];

   if(returnedImage == nil) {
      NSLog(@"Returned Image Nil");
   }
  return returnedImage;
}
```

Comment: For example when put array from photos url and do loop and use by  [SDWebImageManager sharedManager]; to download the images  it download only first image and other urls request did'nt enter to completion block

Comment: I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SDWebImage, then just download the data using the url and dont assign that to imageView and the library you are using will cache it by doing so.